# Correct way of writing a filter query on a geodjango model (finding out if a multipolygon field contains a point)

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango, spatial-query

I am new to geodjango and trying to build an application after going through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/). So, I have this model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class CountryBorder(models.Model):
    f_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    ....
    ....
    #the multipolygonfield on which I want to perform lookup
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I am trying to find the model instance which contains (the model.geom field contains) a point. I tried doing that as described in the documentation:

```
from app_name.models import CountryBorder
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
pnt = Point(23.1827, 75.7682)
CountryBorder.objects.get(geom_contains=pnt)
```

But I get the following error message:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'geom_contains' into field. Choices are: f_code, geom,name.....

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You separate the field name (here `geom`) and lookup (here [**`__contains`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std-fieldlookup-gis-contains), with two consecutive underscores (`__`), not a single underscore, so:

```
from app_name.models import CountryBorder
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

pnt = Point(23.1827, 75.7682)

CountryBorder.objects.get(geom__contains=pnt)
```

Comment: yes I am not getting the same error now, but I think there's something wrong with the coordinates. Is there a way to print the list of coordinates contained within different polygons of a multipolygon field?

Comment: @musical_ant: what error do you get?

Comment: I figured it out, the data set I have contains points in (longitude, latitude) format instead of (latitude, longitude). Thank you for your help :)